# java.lang.Error: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR) Android App

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-console

I've released a simple mobile game for android using unity. However, if you uninstall and reinstall the app from the play store the game crashes every time you try to open it until you clear cache/data. This is not reproducible from development builds, it only occurs with the version that is downloaded from the Play Store.

Details: 
 **Unity 2019.1.13f1,
 Android**.

The Error message I get from google developer console:

```
java.lang.Error: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0000000000000010 Build fingerprint: 'HUAWEI/ELE-L29EEA/HWELE:9/HUAWEIELE-L29/9.1.0.193C431:user/release-keys' Revision: '0' pid: 25899, tid: 25924, name: UnityMain >>> com.UCSsoftware.ColorDrop <<< x0 0000007299f7d610 x1 0000007286559fa0 x2 000000000000010f x3 0000000000000001 x4 0000000000000000 x5 0000000000000000 x6 000000732a7f8000 x7 0000000003dc3ba8 x8 0000000000000000 x9 0000000000000000 x10 0000007283f6b000 x11 0000000000002e1f x12 ffffffffffff8000 x13 ffffffffa260f39e x14 000000000507d7d6 x15 0000007286408cc8 x16 00000073269301a0 x17 00000073268c5524 x18 0000007286408068 x19 000000000000000b x20 0000000000000060 x21 00000072840ee470 x22 000000000000005c x23 00000072855a1000 x24 00000072855a1000 x25 0000007299f20d70 x26 0000000000000002 x27 000000728411ca30 x28 0000000000000000 x29 0000007287784e90 x30 0000007284dfbab0 sp 0000007287784e10 pc 0000007284dfba68 pstate 0000000080000000 at [vdso].(

at split_config. (0)
at split_config. (0)
at split_config. (0)
at split_config. (0)
at split_config. (0)
at split_config. (0)
at split_config. (0)
at base. (0)
```

Comment: It looks like a memory leak. Do you have a suspicion of where this might happen? Post the relevant code if you have any.

Comment: i doubt its a memory leak. i changed the way i save the highscore in the game because i hoped that would fix the problem. Right now im using unitys PlayerPrefs class:                                                                                    
example                                                                                                                                          
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("invertControls", 0);
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("soundEnabled", 1);
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Highscore", 0);
            PlayerPrefs.Save();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug that has been fixed in unity 2019.2.6f1.

You can find more information [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-2019-x-il2cpp-crash-on-android-8.673972/).

Comment: Thank you, i will try to update to a newer version and make an update. I will mark your answer as correct if it works, in a few days when the update is approved by google and goes live.